# ASP.NET: Help button

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-3.5

net APPLIATION dashboard, i need to provide help icon on the screen. For that i have few option as follows

1. I can use AJAX modal popup and register usercontrol having help content and show it on modal popup control on click of help button
2. I can use javascript buble tooltip for help on mouse over/enter of help icon.

Can you suggest me right approach

Answer (score 1):

There is never a "right" or "wrong" approach, certainly not in a clear-cut fashion.  What I personally would do is use jQuery to provide a client-side modal (or modeless) dialog and populate the dialog via AJAX.  In this regard I could have a dynamic help page loading help from a database and I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel on each page so to speak.  jQuery.UI has a decent modal dialog that would work well in this situation so long as you coded up the rest to pull the content.

Comment: Thanks,
Can we say that using asp.net usercontrol on ajax popup will effect my website performance because whenever asp.net page load it registered usercontrol and hence usercontrol page life cycle also execute.
But in case of jquery it doesn't happens

Answer (score 0):

I would also go with a jQuery/JavaScript type popup, I think a correct approach might be to only load the content when its required, ie on icon rollover or on click to reduce overhead.

Comment: Thanks,
Can we say that using asp.net usercontrol on ajax popup will effect my website performance because whenever asp.net page load it registered usercontrol and hence usercontrol page life cycle also execute.
But in case of jquery it doesn't happens

Comment: Having the popup in a UserControl is probably a good idea as it encapsulates all the code, the page lifecycle should be negligible in this case. The call to the database/content should be done via ajax/javascript to populate the help only when required.